# Replacing TWebBrowser with TEdgeBrowser in Delphi 11

Tags: javascript, google-maps, delphi-11-alexandria, tedgebrowser

TEdgeBrowser replaces TWebBrowser.  It is new.
TEdgebrowser is supposed to run Javascript and it does.
I took the same code that I used for TWebBrowser, stripped down to its minimum.  With Google Maps leaving IE, this is imperitive that we able able to make this work with Edge.

If you run the minimal and fully functional code I've provided (less the API key), you will see this works under TWebBrowser.  It works under TWebBrowser because of the HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION fix.
But I see nothing in the EdgeBrowser.  I do have Edge installed on my machine.
I had toggled the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION between IE 11 and Edge.  No difference.

I did a search on TEdgeBrowser and Javascript Google Maps and SO said it was removed by moderators without explanation.

Any input would be deeply appreciated.

```
unit streetMap;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, MSHTML, System.UITypes,
  Buttons, IPPeerClient,Vcl.AppEvnts, Winapi.WebView2, Winapi.ActiveX, Vcl.Edge;


type
  TfrmStreetMap = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    EdgeBrowser1: TEdgeBrowser;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }

    HTMLWindow2: IHTMLWindow2;
    procedure CreateMap(Sender: TObject);

  public

  end;


var
  frmStreetMap: TfrmStreetMap;
  GoogleAPIKey: AnsiString;

implementation

uses
  StrUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

const
  HTMLStrHeader: AnsiString =
  '<html> ' +
  '<head> ' +
    '<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /> ' +
    '<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.47&amp;callback=initMap"></script> '    +
    '<script type="text/javascript"> ' +
    '' +
    '';

  HTMLStr: AnsiString =
    '  function initialize() { ' +

    '    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.000,-84.0000); ' +
    '    var myOptions = { ' +
    '      zoom: 15, ' +
    '      center: latlng, ' +
    '      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP ' +
    '                    }; ' +
    '    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);  '  +
    ' '  +
    '  } ' +

    '</script> ' +
    '</head> ' +
    '<body onload="initialize()"> ' +
    '  <style>        ' +

    '#map_canvas {               ' +
    '        height: 100%;   ' +
    '      }                  ' +
    '      #map_canvas {         ' +
    '        margin-right: 40px;  } ' +
    '    </style>                ' +
    '  <div id="map_canvas"></div> ' +
    '</body> ' +
    '</html> ';

procedure TfrmStreetMap.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ModHTMLStr: AnsiString;
begin
    ModHTMLStr := HTMLStrHeader+ HTMLStr;
    edgebrowser1.ExecuteScript(HTMLStrHeader+ HTMLStr);
end;

procedure TfrmStreetMap.CreateMap(Sender: TObject);
var
  aStream: TMemoryStream;
  ModHTMLStr: AnsiString;
begin
  try
    ModHTMLStr := HTMLStrHeader+ HTMLStr;
    WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
    if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
    begin
      aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        aStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(ModHTMLStr)^, Length(ModHTMLStr));
        aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
        (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
      finally
        aStream.Free;
      end;
      HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin

    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmStreetMap.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TfrmStreetMap.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateMap(Sender);
end;

end.
```

The Form code is below:

```
object frmStreetMap: TfrmStreetMap
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderStyle = bsSingle
  Caption = 'StreetMap'
  ClientHeight = 532
  ClientWidth = 1035
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  Position = poDesigned
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser
    Left = -8
    Top = 4
    Width = 593
    Height = 461
    TabOrder = 0
    ControlData = {
      4C0000004A3D0000A52F00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000004C000000000000000000000001000000E0D057007335CF11AE690800
      2B2E126208000000000000004C0000000114020000000000C000000000000046
      8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000}
  end
  object EdgeBrowser1: TEdgeBrowser
    Left = 591
    Top = 8
    Width = 426
    Height = 457
    TabOrder = 4
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 792
    Top = 496
    Width = 145
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Load into Edge'
    TabOrder = 5
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```